# Ajax & session ids

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

How would you go about knowing that ajax requests are related?

Normally with HTTP-HTML requests, cookies would store a md5 hash representing a session id.

I would like to add, my ajax calls are cross-domain.

**Updated**:

Example:

```
var data1 = 'asdf';
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://differentdomain.com/ajax',
  data: 'data1=' + data1
});
```

Now with this ajax request being made by many clients (browsers/computers). I would like to know that they originated from a single browser session. I thought using a session id might be a solution.

Is there a standard pattern for AJAX & session ids? I am using Java on the server-side.

Comment: Can you clarify "origin"?  Do you mean a different domain?  As in, cross-domain requests?  Or just a different location on the same domain?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: If the requests have a diferent origin, how else do you need the requests to be related to one another?

Comment: @Bryon: How can i differentiate ajax requests made by computer 1 and computer 2?

Comment: Are you using any kind of server-side technology like ASP.NET or PHP?

Comment: I am using Java on the server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using UUID.randomUUID() and check if it has been used yet in my database. Then using the UUID as the session id.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Answer (score 2):

AJAX requests are client-side. Client #1 using IE hits your site and processes any client-side code, all part of one session. Client #2 using Safari hits your site and processes any client-side code, all part of another session.

Unless you generate a session id, there isn't one available to you natively in javascript. If you can, for the sake of uniqueness, it's best to generate or get a session Id from server-side. If not, you can use a method like [this](http://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/javascript-for-setting-session-id-and-visitor-id-cookies/).

If you're using PHP, you could do this:

```
var data1 = 'asdf';
var sessionId = '<?php echo session_id(); ?>';
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'http://differentdomain.com/ajax', 
  data: 'data1=' + data1 + '&sid=' + sessionId
});
```

If you're using ASP.NET, you could do this:

```
var data1 = 'asdf';
var sessionId = '<% =Session.SessionId %>';
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'http://differentdomain.com/ajax', 
  data: 'data1=' + data1 + '&sid=' + sessionId
});
```

If [some java web server] (like Tomcat), you could:

```
var data1 = 'asdf';
var sessionId = '<% session.getId() %>';
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'http://differentdomain.com/ajax', 
  data: 'data1=' + data1 + '&sid=' + sessionId
});
```

Comment: Any idea on doing this with java?

Comment: Java would be the language you would use, but you'd have to be running through a web platform of some sort. Maybe you could use Tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/)?